# Calling Asp.net web API from Android Studio View

Tags: android, android-studio, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem while accessing asp.net web API through android studio project. My web API connect with the database through Entity Framework. I want to call the list of Merchants through API Merchant Controller from android merchant view. Here is my HttpGet method for Merchant:

```
public class MerchantController : ApiController
    {
        private DostiCardDBEntities merchantEntities = new DostiCardDBEntities();

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage listOfMerchant() {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, merchantEntities.MerchantTables.ToList());
        }
}
```

I access list of Merchants through AsyncTask doInBackground method i-e

```
private class ExecuteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
        String jsonText = "";
        HttpsURLConnection connection;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://169.254.80.80:6040/api/Merchant");
                connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                int byteCharacter;

                while ((byteCharacter = inputStream.read()) != -1){
                    char c = (char) byteCharacter;
                    jsonText += c;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? Is your app crashing, performing unexpectedly, etc.? Please elaborate.

Comment: My app crashed When i use HttpsURLConnection and when i use HttpURLConnection or URLConnection then onPostExecute method Toast statement returns null @NarayanAcharya

Comment: Your endpoint is "http://.." so using HttpsUrlConnection might not be right. When using the other option the inputstream being null probably meant that the request was not successful or no response was received. Therefore it is recommended that you check the status of the response before reading from the inputstream. Also, check in browser if that endpoint works or not before trying this.

Comment: I'm new in android.. how can i check the status of the response ?? @NarayanAcharya

Comment: But did you check in your browser if that URL does indeed return something? This is the doc for HttpUrlConnection - http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html. getResponseCode() is one of the methods it has. I see that your still using HttpsUrlConnection. Move to HttpUrlConnection and use getResponseCode to check if it 200. If it is then you can read content maybe.

Comment: But before all of that just check if that endpoint is accessible in a browser and does it actually return anything.

Comment: oh yes. I check it by using getResponseCode. It returns 400 status code... i-e Bad request :( @NarayanAcharya

Answer (score 0):

By default C# Web Api isn't accessible out side the `localhost` i.e., in your LAN network. What you have to do is goto your project path and inside your project folder there is one folder called `.vs` which is hidden by default (you can see that by changing your Folder and Search options settings).

Now open `.vs` folder and goto `config` folder and there open `applicationhost.xml` file using any text editor.

After opening find out the following line

```
<bindings>
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:6040:localhost" />
</bindings>
```

And update above line like this

```
<bindings>
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:6040:localhost" />
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:6040:*" />
</bindings>
```

Where, `6040` is your project's port address. Save and exit from editor. Now this allows you to access the Web Api throughout your LAN connection. (some times you have to start Visual Studio with Admin Privileges).

Now in your Mobile Phone open any browser and type the address like this

```
http://169.254.80.80:6040
```

If you get some response from your api it works perfectly.

Comment: I have already done. see below... but still I've a problem.. 
getting Status code = 400
`<bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:6040:localhost" />
                  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:6040:169.254.80.80" />
                </bindings>`

Comment: I said `bindingInformation="*:6040:*"` which allows all the IP address within your LAN to access your Web API. And in your controller change `listOfMerchant()` to `GetListOfMerchant()` and give a try. Check this URL in mobile phone browser.

Comment: And I forgot to mention that if it is not working turn off your Firewall.

Comment: No change at all :( it returns nothing with status code 400

Comment: It returns HTTP Error 400: The request hostname is invalid

Answer (score 0):

You could check if that is your public IP, or check if it is accessible outside your domain, as your device should be outside your domain, also check if you have granted internet access in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

you should change HttpsURLConnection to HttpURLConnection because your URL using protocol http not https