# how to make call a asp .net web api in android studio for a simple log in page

Tags: android, asp.net, android-studio

i have written a web api in asp.net but I am not able to figure out how to call it  in android studio. Please help as I am new to programming. Its a simple log in application. Please help. I have tried using jtdc driver also even then app does not create connection tell that the connection object is null.

```
namespace WebApplication2.Controllers

{
public class EmployeesController : ApiController
{

    public IEnumerable<Login> Get()
    {
        using(AndroidTryEntities entities= new AndroidTryEntities())
        {
            return entities.Logins.ToList();
        }
    }

    public bool Getd(string user, string pass)
    {
        using (AndroidTryEntities entities = new AndroidTryEntities())
        {
            var result= entities.Logins.FirstOrDefault(e => e.UserName == user && e.Password == pass);
            if(result!=null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}


}
```

Comment: **Google** it my friend

Comment: @NileshRathod did it but could not find what i was searching for.

Comment: just in 10 seconds i search it http://instinctcoder.com/how-to-call-asp-net-web-api-from-android-studio/

Comment: Thanks @NileshRathod I was following this but could not understand it at all.

Comment: check out this links https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&hs=eDm&channel=fs&dcr=0&q=how+to+use+asp+net+web+api+in+android+studio&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN-eyXjZrXAhWBNo8KHS_SAasQ1QIIaygE&biw=1301&bih=641

Comment: @NileshRathod is this link useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184846/calling-asp-net-web-api-from-android-studio-view how do I have to proceed I have already made the layout how to call the api? Please help. I have tried all the links just not making sense for a log in app.

Comment: not that link there are many links also check it

Comment: @NileshRathod I did try almost all nothing makes sense trying this from past three days. But thanks  a lot.

Comment: search how to make a post request and then put the url  as ''http://yoursite.com/Employee" and post to this url